# DietPi xfce doesn't show USB Device what SD connected

Tags: usb, pi-4

DietPi **xfce** doesn't show *USB Device* what SD connected!

I am using USB Device what SD connected, but xfce doesn't show Devices.

I check using

```
lsusb
```

but Device name was *appeard*.

Other OS like debian-64, raspbian-buster, debian-nspawn64.

What should I do?buster

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Which OS you are using now?

Comment: Actually I could solve with using dietpimanager. OS name is dietpi, which is light os for raspi 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it now!

If you are using dietpi OS, chose DietPi-Drive Manager at `dietpi-launcher` (You need to run it root).

Thanks!

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: Thanks for your advise =D
I will improve more better.